# Answering "amen" to "Ahavas olam" in the evening but not in the morning

Tags: blessing, shema, maariv, shacharis-morning-prayer, amen

*Mishna B'rura* ([61:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=184)) cites a difference of opinion regarding whether one should respond "*amen*" to the *shatz*'s (leader's) blessing immediately before "*Sh'ma*" or should, on the contrary, finish saying the blessing along with the *shatz* in order to avoid saying "*amen*".

I know of people who act according to one view, and of people who act according to the other.

But I also know of people who finish saying the blessing along with the *shatz* during *shacharis* (the morning prayer service) and answer "*amen*" to the *shatz* during *maariv* (the evening service). Does anyone have a source or reason or provenance for this?

Comment: Is Maariv being davened early? If it's at a time when Keriat Shema is not being done for the Mitzva, then there is no reason (aside from perhaps _lo plug_) to not say Amen, as that bracha is definitely not functioning as a birkat hamitzva where hefsek would be a problem. (Same would apply to a late Shacharit.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, this is at any _maariv_.

Comment: It might be based on their reading of the Shulchan Aruch and Rama (OC 59:4), where the Shulchan Aruch says to "recite *birkas yotzeir* and *arvis* together with the *sh'liach tzibbur*," upon which the Rama adds that one should "hurry to finish before the *sh'liach tzibbur* and answer *amein* after him." Then the Shulchan Aruch proceeds to write: "And one should not answer *amein* after the conclusion of *habocheir b'amo Yisra'el b'ahava*, for that would be a *hefsek*," upon which the gloss adds "and see later on in Siman 61." (In 61:3, the Rama says one should also answer in the morning).

Comment: ... If this is really the source of the practice, it seems to be based on an incorrect interpretation of the opinions of the Shulchan Aruch and Rama.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83836

Comment: Also about a morning/evening difference in this benediction: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89277