# Why do some people say the end of the 2nd bracha before Shema with the Shat"z?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, shema, bircas-krias-shema

I have noticed in many shuls (mainly Nusach Ashkenaz, though, I have seen in Nusach Sefard, as well) I have attended that some people conclude the end of the 2nd bracha before the Shema (Shacharit - ends with הבוחר בעמו ישראל באהבה ; Ma'ariv ends with אוהב עמו ישראל ) together with the Shat"z.

I guess this is a minhag? What is the origin / reason for doing this as opposed to concluding the bracha **before** the chazzan? Is there a problem with pausing between the end of the bracha and the beginning of Shema?

Comment: Some people also do this for the other brachot around shema

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28568

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch (O.C. 59:4):](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.59.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וְלֹא יַעֲנֶה אָמֵן אַחַר סִיּוּם הַבּוֹחֵר בְּעַמּוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּאַהֲבָה, מִשּׁוּם דְּהָוֵי הֶפְסֵק
>
> One should not answer amen after the conclusion of '...הַבּוֹחֵר'
>   because it is an interruption.

The [Rema (61:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.61.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) disagrees:

> רַק יֹאמַר אָמֵן אַחַר הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר כְּשֶׁמְּסַיֵּם הַבְּרָכָה, וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין, וְנָכוֹן הוּא

The [Mishna Brurah (59 s.k. 24 and 25)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.59.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that they are disagreeing about the nature of the bracha. The S.A. sees it as any other blessing that one makes on a mitzvah etc., so there cannot be a hefsek between this blessing and its subject, the Shema. The Rema sees it as different from all other blessings on mitzvos, as evidenced by the lack of structure standard to such blessings.
M.B. goes on to say that the general consensus of the achronim is in accordance with the Rema, but that there are those who nevertheless advise to finish with the shliach tzibbur, thereby eliminating the possible hefsek of an amen (one does not answer amen to a blessing he concludes together with the shliach tzibbur - see M.B. 51 s.k. 3 - otherwise one is generally obligated to answer amen to blessings - see S.A. 215:2).

Comment: Note there's no point in not saying Amen when praying outside the time for Shema (and in fact since you can say Amen it's better to do so). Also one shouldn't drown out the Chazzan if saying along with him (but say it along in an undertone), since some people may be fulfilling their obligation with him. These are common mistakes for people to make when they take on this "chumra" without knowing enough about it.

Comment: It's not clear the Shulchan Arukh is even talking about BeTzibbur. He may be saying not to say Amen after your own blessing, but after the Chazzan he agrees you can. See two answers in the Beit Yosef (and his note about the popular custom!) and the Beiur Halakha too. Indeed R Yonah's source is the Rambam who's pretty clearly talking about Amen after your own blessing.

Comment: While I didn't ask in OP, do any of these sources mention WHY one is not allowed to pause between the bracha and the start of Shema?

Comment: @DanF No one said one isn't allowed to pause then...

Comment: @DanF It creates  a possible obligation to answer amen, depending if you're going with S.A. or Rema.

Comment: @Jay "depending if you're going with S.A. or Rema" Only for a certain read of the Shulchan Arukh. Again, the simple read if you follow to the Beit Yosef is he agrees that you say Amen if you finished before the Chazzan, and the line in the Shulchan Arukh is about if you are alone that you don't say Amen after your own blessing to avoid Hefsek. In other words, this chumra of the Mishna Berura (against longstanding Minhag) probably is for an opinion that doesn't exist.

Comment: "one does not answer amen to a blessing he concludes together with the shliach tzibbur - see M.B. 51 s.k. 3" This isn't true about blessings which conclude sections according to the MB. So according to the opinion that you do say Amen after your own blessing here (eg. Geonim), you haven't gained anything by finishing with the Chazzan. In other words, this chumra of the Mishna Berura (against longstanding Minhag) doesn't even completely solve the issue "in accordance with all views".

Comment: @Jay The Rambam is Shema 1:17. He says not to say Amen because of Hefsek before Shema, but he does think it's the end of a section that we have to ask should we say Amen. Here you have the Amen written out in R Saadya Gaon's siddur http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8&pgnum=85 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8&pgnum=73 . The Gra OC 51 (also Mishna Berura 215) though seems to say like you. This could depend on if Emet ve[X] has no Malkhut because it's short or because it's Samukh.

Comment: @DoubleAA The M.B. there in 51 says the reason to say amen in certain instances  even if you finish with the s.t. is because there are "many" poskim who hold that in those cases one would answer amen to his own bracha anyway. I don't know how many are 'many' nor what the count is in our case. But I do find it interesting that when listing his examples, he skips over birchat k.s. and doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Jay Well, yes because the ShA you cited in this answer says no Amen, seemingly talking about BeYachid, so he's ruling against RaSaG above. But the idea here is if were trying to be Machmir and find a way to not say Amen and be doing the right thing even according to those who would say Amen in some cases, we havent fully solved the issue. Plus not everyone is so convinced finishing with the Chazzan does anything. See the MA OC 51 who doesn't like the ruling of the ShA. So yes we rule if you finish with the Chazzan you LeChumra don't say Amen, but thats not an ideal position to put yourself in